# Cocoa ASIHTTP - HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: cocoa, asihttprequest

i am using ASIHTTP [(http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)](http://%28http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/%29) to handle communication

standard web communication is ok, but when i want to download files, aim getting

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

on different servers

this is my ASIFormDataRequest

```
ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setDownloadDestinationPath:destinationPath];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Connection"     value:@"Keep-Alive"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Keep-Alive"     value:@"timeout=1000, max=20"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Language"    value:@"en"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Charset" value:@"utf-8"];
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:YES];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];

[request setPostValuesWithDictionary:postDictionary];
```

but in the didFinish aim getting a ASIHTTPRequest with response message 405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use

```
ASIHTTPRequest * request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

instead of

```
ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're doing a POST instead of a GET to download the file when you're using ASIFormDataRequest (which afaik POSTS to a form).

You should normally fetch files using GET, which means you should probably use ASIHTTPRequest instead.